# How to install external libraries with Portable Python?

Tags: python, numpy, installation, portability

I can't install Python on my machine due to administrator privileges, but I did download/open Portable Python successfully. I am on a Windows 7 64-bit machine. How would I be able to use the external libraries from before, such as Numpy or Gmpy?

Answer (score 4):

easy_install is trying to install from source. gmpy and gmpy2 are C extensions and require the presence of a compatible C compiler and other libraries (GMP; and MPFR and MPC for gmpy2). Installing from source is frequently difficult on Windows. The installers include a precompiled version of the extension.

One option is to extract the compiled binary from the installer. [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) is able to open the installer file and you can extract the binary. In a standard Python installation, the extracted binary just needs to be placed in the site-packages directory. If necessary, you can do the extraction on another system and copy the file.

You can also use the zipfile module to extract the compiled extension. Here is an example. You will need to modify the exact file locations to reflect your system.

```
>>> import zipfile
>>> f=zipfile.ZipFile('gmpy2-2.0.0.win-amd64-py3.3.exe','r')
>>> f.namelist()
['PLATLIB/gmpy2-2.0.0-py3.3.egg-info', 'PLATLIB/gmpy2.pyd']
>>> f.extract('PLATLIB/gmpy2.pyd')
'C:\\Python33\\PLATLIB\\gmpy2.pyd'
```

Comment: I used this method to extract pycrypto package, there are many modules in this package, I used `f.extractall()` but didn't know where to put the extracted files

Answer (score 2):

Do the following:

- Find an already compiled version of the desired package - Christoph Gohlke mantains an excelent collection [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) - download it and put it in a folder (say C:\temp).
- In your Portable Python installation find the Scripts folder (usually under the Apps folder) and open a command prompt there.
- From the Scripts folder type the command `easy_install C:\temp\numpy-MKL-1.8.0.win32-py2.7.exe` (change the exe file name for whatever is the name of your installer).

Test if the installation succeeded:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> print numpy.__version__
1.8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

please refer to https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/portablepython/BVQOHFNXilU

According to that, for most packages, you should be able to conduct an easy install into your Portable Python root folder and then import it as normal in your python script.

Answer (score 0):

For most external packages, I have been able to import them as follows:

1. Extract the package source from the appropriate `.whl` file on PyPI into a custom 'include' folder on the disk/stick with Portable Python installed.

   1. In my case, this is `F:\py\include`  -- whatever you choose, **be sure** the path to this folder has no spaces or special characters in it, or else Portable Python won't parse it correctly when added to `PYTHONPATH`.
   2. Wheels are just ZIP files; rename the `.whl` to `.zip` and Windows Explorer will open it right up.
   3. Usually you want to retrieve the subfolder within the `.whl` whose name is just the package name you're interested in: `numpy`, `sympy`, etc.
2. Add the path to this include folder to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable:

   1. In Windows Explorer, right-click on 'Computer' and select 'Properties'
   2. This is a bit version-dependent, but select something like 'Advanced system settings' (Win7) or the 'Performance' or 'Advanced' tab (WinXP).
   3. Click 'Environment variables'
   4. Under 'System variables', look for `PYTHONPATH`. If it's there, select it and click 'Edit.' If not, click 'New'.
   5. If you're adding it new, type `PYTHONPATH` as the 'Variable name.' Either way, Add the path to your custom include folder into 'Variable value.'  If other paths are already in there, separate your path from any prior one with a semicolon. **DO NOT** put a space between the semicolon and your new path!  Portable Python apparently interprets entries with a leading space as being *relative paths*, with the reference folder being the Portable Python installation folder.
   6. Click 'OK' as needed to save the settings and clear the dialogs.

In some cases where a "formal" installation process is required, this hasn't always worked.  I think `sympy` was one case where I had to compile it before transferring it to `F:\py\include`.  Also, I had a particularly [rough time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179534/how-can-i-install-h5py-with-portable-python-v2-7) with `h5py`, but eventually got it to work by installing it into a 'normal' version of Python 2.7 and copying the resultant `h5py` folder over to `F:\py\include`.