# how to install libraries in portable Python 3.2.1.1

Tags: python, pdf

I have installed Portable Python 3.2.1.1 on windows 8  and i also have installed pypdf2
 using `setup.py install` command on cmd.
 but when I try to import the module it is giving me an error

```
 "import error: no module named pypdf2"
```

is installation on portable python different?

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171658/how-to-install-external-libraries-with-portable-python

Answer (score 1):

All efforts to make this work with PortablePython 3.2.5.1 failed. But this is the Portable Python 2.7.5.1 version of it. I did it on Windows 7! 
 [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82Pvq.png)

1. I downloaded **PyPDF2** from https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2 and extracted the folder.
2. I found the folder **PyPDF2-master** and went into it to reveal **PyPDF2**.
3. I copied the folder **PyPDF2** into the path **"Python 2.7.5.1\App\Lib"**
4. I went back to Portable **"Python 2.7.5.1\App"** and started python.exe

I've also attached a screenshot. I hope this will also work for you.