# Installing additional modules for Portable Python 3.2

Tags: python, portability

I have Portable Python 3.2 on a USB drive as I am often writing programs on many different computers. I wish to install GMPY for the Portable Python however when I go on the website to download GMPY the versions I find are for direct computer install and not a manual install on the USB. I can not do this for all computers I work on as I do not have admin access for all of them. Could someone please guide me through installing GMPY on my USB? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The executable files that can be downloaded from PyPI (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmpy2) are just zip files in disguise. All you need to do is extract the `gmpy2.pyd` file and place it in the `site-packages` directory. See [How to install external libraries with Portable Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171658/how-to-install-external-libraries-with-portable-python) for more details.

*Note: The following comments are specific to the Windows operating system.*

Python extensions can be written in either Python, C, or a combination of both. The source code is usually distributed as a `.tar.gz` or `.zip` file. Extensions that use C are difficult to distribute as source code since most Windows systems lack a C compiler to compile the C code into a `.pyd` file.

To solve this issue, pre-compiled versions can be distributed as `.exe` files. These `.exe` files are really zip files with a small installer program. Unfortunately, the installer only works with the Python interpreters from www.python.org. A new "wheel" format (`.whl`) has been developed that doesn't include an installer but relies on an external Python Installation Program (aka `pip`) that extracts the files from a `.whl` file and copies them to `site-packages`.

For `gmpy2`, you can just extract the `.pyd` file and copy it to the `site-packages` directory.

For `bitarray`, you will need to download a pre-compiled file from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).
`bitarray` uses a combination of Python and C and more than one file will need to be copied. Specifically, you will need to create a sub-directory called `bitarray` inside the `site-packages` directory and then copy `_bitarray.pyd` and `__init__.py` to `site-packages\bitarray`.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to install bitarray this way as well but I could not find any .pyd file in the .tar.gz file I downloaded from PyPI. Any ideas as to how I would be able to install this?