# How can I install h5py with Portable Python v2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, h5py, portable-python

I am doing some Python 2.7 development work on multiple computers, on some of which I do not have rights to install software.  Thus, I am using [Portable Python](http://portablepython.com/).  One of the packages I need to use is `h5py`; however, since Portable Python installs without modifying the registry, the `h5py` installer doesn't see it as a valid Python installation.  Also, simply extracting the `h5py` source to a custom `F:\py\include` folder and adding `F:\py\include` to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable doesn't work, as `import h5py` results in an `ImportError: Cannot import name _errors` exception.

How do I install `h5py` with Portable Python 2.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install [Python 2.7](https://www.python.org/downloads/) onto a computer for which you have sufficient administrative rights.
2. Install the [appropriate version](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/h5py) of `h5py` into this Python installation.
3. Find the `h5py` subfolder within the Python install (typically `.\Lib\site-packages\h5py`) and copy it to the `F:\py\include` folder mentioned (make sure to add `F:\py\include` to `PYTHONPATH`).  See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171658/how-to-install-external-libraries-with-portable-python/30179552#30179552) for more details.
4. Uninstall the 'official' version of Python, if desired.